# Sound API vs External Program - Quality

Tags: java, audio

So I tested downsampling a music track in Java by using the [`Javax.Sound API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html)

First of all we had the original `mp3` which was then converted to `.wav` to accept Javas audio `AudioFormat`. Then I used `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioFormat targetFormat, AudioInputStream sourceStream)` to downsample my .wav file.

Here you can see the original mp3 file in Audacity:

[image: Original mp3 File]

After converting it by using [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) and applying Javas Sound API on it, the downsampled track looked like this:

[image: Java downsample]

However, by using another program, [dBPoweramp](https://www.dbpoweramp.com/), it looked like this:

[image: downsampled in db]

You can see that the `amplitudes` of the wave are higher than in the version i downsampled with `Java`.
Therefore it sounds louder and a bit more like the original .mp3 file, where as my own file sounds very quiet compared to the original.

Now my Questions:
How can i achieve this effect? Is it better to have higher amps or are they just cut of like you see in the picture sampled by dBPoweramp. Why ist there any difference anyway?

Comment: Downsampling usually affects the quality, that's the whole point: you give a little bit of quality for gain in data size. That's taken straight from definition.

Comment: You should read my question first i think

Comment: I've read your question and it has nothing to do with it's title, I just responded to the title. To your question: this is accually unwanted effect. It seems to sound better, but it does not. This explain why: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness_war

Comment: i updated the title, thanks for the wikipedia article!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by *quality* here, but it's no surprise whatsoever that nature of a downsampled signal will be different to the original as it will have been filtered to remove frequencies that would violate the [nyqist rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) at the new sample frequency.

We would therefore expect that the gain of down-sampled signal would be lower than that of original.  From that perspective, the signal produced by JLayer looks far more plausible than that of dbPoweramp.

The second graph appears to have higher gain than the original, so I suspect that there is *make-up gain* applied, and possibly dynamic range compression and brick-wall limiting (this signal has periods which appear to have peaks at the limit).  Or worse, it's simply clipped.

And this brings us back to the definition of *quality*: It's subjective. Lots of commercial music *is* heavily compressed and brick-wall limited as part of the production process for a whole variety of reasons. One of which is artistic effect. It seems you're getting more of this from dbPoweramp, and this may well be flattering to your taste and the content.

It is probably not a clean conversion. In any objective measurement of system performance (e.g. [PSNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio)), the quality would be lower.

If objective quality is what you're after, much better performance is achieved in rendering the mp3 into a lower sample rather than decoding to PCM and then downsampling.

As a final word of caution: Audacity is doing some processing on the signal in order to render the time-aplitude graph.  I suspect it is showing the max amplitude per point in the x-axis.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Most of my questions are answered now. But I cant render the mp3 directly to  wav and downsample it on the way, because its not provided by java :( I can only achieve `WAV, AIFF, or AU` conversion.